# NSFetchedResultsController crashing when creating it, objc_exception_throw

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am receiving a **objc_exception_throw** when creating my `NSFetchedResultsController`. I am relatively new to iOS programming so I am still getting the hang of debugging iOS crashes.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
lazy var parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    if let managedObjectContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
        return managedObjectContext
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
    }()

lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("GameDate", inManagedObjectContext: self.parentContext!)
    request.entity = entity
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.parentContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    performFetchFromDb()
    setupTableView()
}
```

I am getting the crash on this line:

`let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.parentContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)`

Does this crash have something to do with my context?

Comment: Stack trace and error, we're not magicians :)

Comment: @Schemetrical What?! You're not magicians?! Why am I even on here then!! Haha I actually figured it out, I didn't put a sort descriptor on there. I'm going to make my own answer when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing an `NSSortDescriptor` in my fetch request. This fixed it:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let request = NSFetchRequest()

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("GameDate", inManagedObjectContext: self.parentContext!)
    request.entity = entity

    let gameTimeSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "gameTime", ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [gameTimeSort]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.parentContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```